# Core Data: With a NSFetchRequest Is there a way to get fetched properties when the result type is set to NSDictionaryResultType

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have an application that uses two separate core data stores. One for user data, and one for read-only content data. In order to create relationships between them, it is of course forbidden to use relationships, and so references to the content store are managed by ids.

This works fine in most cases, but for some particular fetches it is proving difficult.

Take the following example: Say I have an application that has a few hundred movies (with a record for each stored in the read-only store) and whenever a user watches one a record is created in the writable user store. I might set up my model to have one Entity called Movie, and another called MovieHistory.

Movie has:
an attribute called identifier (NSNumber).

MovieHistory has:
an attribute called movieIdentifier (a cross-store reference to Movie),
a viewDate attribute (NSDate),
and a fetched property 'movie' with the destination set to Movie and a predicate of (SELF.identifier == $FETCH_SOURCE.movieIdentifier).

Say I now want to get the last 10 movies watched, without duplicates (if I watch a movie that I previously watched it should jump to the top of the list). I'd like to be able to use the following code:

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"MovieHistory"];

NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"viewDate" ascending:NO];

NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MovieHistory" inManagedObjectContext: moc];
NSAttributeDescription* movieIdentifierDesc = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"movieIdentifier"];
NSFetchedPropertyDescription *movieDesc = [entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"movie"];

[request setFetchLimit: limit];
[request setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: dateDescriptor]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: movieIdentifierDesc, movieDesc, nil]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject: movieIdentifierDesc]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest: request error: &error];

if(error != nil)
    NSLog(@"Error fetching last viewed movies: %@", error);

return results;
```

This code throws an exception stating that the fetched property ('movie' in 'MovieHistory') is an invalid property to use in this case. You can't use fetched properties when using NSDictionaryResultType. However, you also can't use setPropertiesToGroupBy: without the return type being NSDictionaryResultType. I need grouping in order to sort by date and remove duplicate Movies.

It works fine when I remove the fetched property from the array sent to setPropertiesToFetch:. But then of course I would have to pull out each MovieRecord one-by-one in a loop.

What is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Is there a way to do this without having to resort to fetching the IDs and then looping through the results one-by-one?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly follow your whole post, however...

You can issue two separate fetch operations.  The first gets the MovieHistory objects from that database.

Put all the movie identifiers into a collection, and then fetch on the movie database, using the IN keyword.

```
NSPredicate *moviePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"identifier IN %@", allMovieIdentifiers];
```

It is not quite as elegant as some other solutions, but it is easy to write, and, more importantly, easy to read, understand, and change.  Remember optimize first for programmers.

Comment: Hi Jody, thanks for your response. However, I need the order of the fetched items preserved. (The code I posted above fetches the last 10 movies viewed, with the most recently viewed at the top, and no duplicates).

Comment: Fair enough. Not sure why a second fetch prevents using the original sorted results.  The second fetch just contains all the movie objects... much better than fetching individually, and the data is so small a search through the second array is simple.  Don't be afraid to be simple ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I could do the second fetch, receiving the unordered list of movies, and then order them according to the original fetch. So: 1) Fetch ordered movieIdentifiers 2) Fetch unordered Movies 3) order unordered Movies now in memory with results of original fetch.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'd do it, at least at first.  It is simple, easy to understand, and does not have much extra overhead.  When accessing a second table, the second fetch has to happen anyway.  By using IN, you limit yourself to only two fetches to the database to find the records.  Rearranging 10 items in memory is about as close to nothing as you can get.

Comment: Great, that'll do! Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simpler. Thanks!